# Retrieve arithmetic from column and use it to calculate a value

Tags: sql, sqlite

Assume the following data:

```
TABLE articles
id          price
-----------------
1           100
2           200

TABLE conditions
id          modifier
-----------------
EXW         *1
FCA         *1.5
OT1         +125
OT2         *1.5+100
```

What I would like returned is this:

```
id          price         condition
----------------------------------
1           100           EXW
2           200           EXW
1           150           FCA
2           300           FCA
1           225           OT1
2           325           OT1
1           250           OT2
2           400           OT2
```

Basically, the code should take the price and the modifier (which is basically an incomplete formula) and execute it. The formula would likely require a slightly different format (perhaps `price*1.5` or for more complex variations `(price + 100) * 1.5`

The alternative solution using only a multiplier and addition would be fairly simple, but things could get messy if division or multiple operations would be required (addition and then multiplication of that - see above example).

I am using SQLite 3.8.8.2 but I would be interested in implementations in other databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sp_executesql` to evaluate any expression:

```
DECLARE @calc varchar(max);
set @calc = '10*4.5*0.5'

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @result float
set @sql = N'set @result = ' + @calc
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@result float output', @result out
select @result
```

This is a higlevel idea and code!
To get it fit in your requirement, what you can do is, you can create a `StoredProcedure` to evaluate such expressions and return result from that, and in your query just call that procedure!

**Code:**

```
Create Procedure SP_EvaluateExpression
@expression nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @result float
set @sql = N'set @result = ' + @expression
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@result float output', @result out
return @result
END
```

Your query should look like this:

> select articles.ID,CONCAT(articles.Price,modifier) as
>   PRICE,conditions.ID as 'condition' from articles cross join
>   conditions

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use select without join but juste selected table, By cons I do not know if the column operands will not be a problem

```
Select articles.id,articles.Price*modifier, condition.id as condition
from articles, condition
```